# Integrating two function by substitution or by parts

Tags: integration

How do I integrate these

$\displaystyle\int \frac{x^{\ln x}\ln  x}{x}\, dx$

and

$\displaystyle\int (\ln x)^{\ln x}\Biggl[\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{x} \Biggr]\,dx$

After using substitution I always stop at dead end

Comment: Use ```\``` before some functions to get it formatted nicely. E.g. ```\ln(x)``` to get $\ln(x)$.

Comment: What did you try substituting and what did you get? There's a fairly obvious choice for what you might want to substitute.

Comment: I used $u=\ln x$

Comment: Can you explain how that ends in a dead end?

Comment: For the first integral i end with $\int e^{u^2}$

Comment: You need to [edit] your question including details such as that rather than posting them in comments. And show your work.

Comment: @HarshitGupta You end up with $\int ue^{u^2}du$ which can be integrated by another substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Differentiate $\;x^{\ln x}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\mathrm e^{\ln^2x}\;$ and $\;(\ln x)^{\ln x}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\mathrm e^{\ln x\ln(\ln x)}$.

Comment: What is this def on top of equal sign ?

Comment: It a way to recall the right-hand side is the definition of the left-hand side.

Comment: Thanks man now it is solvable :)